# JPanel won't show up in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Why does my JPanel not show in JFrame after button is clicked.
There's my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"1", "Marcin Zelek", "537573656"},
                {"2", "Krzysztof Tomala", "324159103"},
                {"3", "Zbigniew S", "324159104"},
            },
            new String[] {
                "#", "Name", "Phone number"
            }
        ));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(214);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(246);
        table.setBounds(12, 103, 426, 185);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);

        JButton btnDodajNowy = new JButton("Dodaj nowy");
        btnDodajNowy.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);// Creating the JPanel
                panel.setBounds(0, 243, 286, 150);
                panel.setVisible(true);

                JButton button = new JButton("New button");
                button.setBounds(12, 12, 117, 25);
                panel.add(button);

                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            }
        });
        btnDodajNowy.setBounds(12, 30, 117, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDodajNowy);

        JButton btnUsuZaznaczone = new JButton("Usuń zaznaczone");
        btnUsuZaznaczone.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                int[] selection = table.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
                {
                    model.removeRow(selection[i]-i);
                }
            }
        });
        btnUsuZaznaczone.setBounds(141, 30, 204, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUsuZaznaczone);

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: If you used the layout managers by their intended, you wouldn't have this problem. If you need further help, clarify your question more including describing your intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should use actionListener instead:

```
btnDodajNowy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();// Creating the JPanel
        panel.setBounds(0, 243, 286, 150);
        JButton button = new JButton("New button");
        button.setBounds(12, 12, 117, 25);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.repaint();
    }
});
```

and also:

1. You don't need to pass `null` as a parameter to the `JPanel` constructor
2. You might want to add a `frame.repaint()`
3. You don't need to set the `JPanel` to visible via `setVisible()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is being added, however, it is hiding below the `JTable`. The quickest fix is this:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    //...
    panel.setBounds(0, 300, 286, 150); // 300 is on the y axis
    //...
    // then render the frame again:
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
}
```

However, I suggest to rewrite it a little:

```
this.generalPanel = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(generalPanel);
...
generalPanel.add(table);
```

This way you'll get a good Layout for the topmost container.

Comment: After setting up 300 and frame.revalidate() I still don't see the panel.

Comment: Yes. You need to `revalidate` and `repaint` too.

Comment: Also, for debugging, you can try this: `panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));`

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to present the panel in same jframe where you added the button you probably should use CardLayout here is the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html